# Veracode Github Action ignores baseline file

Tags: github-actions, veracode, baseline

I'm running a Github Action with a step that runs a code scanning utility called `veracode` (see [docs](https://docs.veracode.com/r/veracode_cli_static_analysis_integration#github)). One of the parameters references a file (containing known, excluded issues) that I know is in the directory but seems not to be found.
This is the output from the step (note the `md5sum` which outputs the right value):

```
Run pwd
  pwd**m
  ls -l**m
  md5sum veracode-baseline.json**m
  ./veracode static scan scan-me.zip --app-id 123 --baseline-file veracode-baseline.json**m
  shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {***}
  env:
    ...
    VERACODE_APP_ID: 123
    VERACODE_API_KEY_ID: ***
    VERACODE_API_KEY_SECRET: ***
    ...
/home/runner/work/my-repo/my-repo
total 128424
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root   root        19***6 Mar  4 16:37 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker      1355 Mar  5 22:29 Notes.md
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root   root         897 Mar  4 16:37 README
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker       499 Mar  5 22:29 README.md
...
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker   8381***4*** Mar  5 22:32 scan-me.zip
...
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root   122728448 Mar  4 16:44 veracode
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker    327389 Mar  5 22:29 veracode-baseline.json
c4c4f61f4d586a24ab***73***751b8d8e63  veracode-baseline.json
----------------------------------------------------------------
Veracode Static Analysis Scan
...
```

The result of this step is the same **as if the file did not exist**. I can run the same command on my workstation successfully.

Why does the analysis ignore the baseline file?

Answer (score 0):

After contacting Veracode support (issue 00842308) I understand I am supposed to be using either:

1. [Pipeline Scan](https://docs.veracode.com/r/Pipeline_Scan)
2. [Github Workflow Integration](https://docs.veracode.com/r/GitHub_Workflow_Integration_for_Repo_Scanning)

They did not answer my question about why my approach was not working.

Also, **Github Workflow Integration doesn't have a baseline feature** and requires Github org-level setup that isn't available to me (inside a large organization). So I'll try Pipeline Scan instead.